# SQLAlchemy generates its own primary keys?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, vertica

I've started integrating SQLAlchemy into my app, to work with **HP Vertica** database.
Basic functionality worked fine so far, but something very weird happens now:

One table has an auto_increment "id" column.
The model that's mapped to this table looks something like this:

```
class MyModel(ModelBase):
    __tablename__ = "sometable"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    somefield = Column(Integer)
    otherfield = Column(Integer)
```

So, I'm creating a new `MyModel` object and add it to the session like this:

```
my_model = MyModel(
            somefield=...,
            otherfield=...
)
session.add(my_model)
```

Not passing an "id" argument, since it's auto_increment.
When calling `session.commit()`, I get an error from Vertica:
*Cannot insert into or update IDENTITY/AUTO_INCREMENT column "id"*

I checked the exception to see what SQL statement was executed, and I saw that **a random value was passed to "id" field:**

```
INSERT INTO "schemaname"."sometable" (id, somefield, otherfield) VALUES (3000001, 8781, 164)
```

**Things I've tried to do and didn't work:**

- Pass `autoincrement=True` and/or `default=None` to `id` in the model
- Explicitly pass `id=None` when creating a new `MyModel` instance - SQLAlchemy still passed a random value...

**NOTES:**

- To work with SQLAlchemy and Vertica, I use the [vertica_python](https://github.com/uber/vertica-python) driver, and [sqlalchemy-vertica-python dialect](https://github.com/LocusEnergy/sqlalchemy-vertica-python), which is an inheritor of sqlalchemy's Postgres dialect. I tried to blame the dialect for this error, but I looked at it's code (it's pretty tiny) and it doesn't seem to affect this at all.
- SQLAlchemy version = 1.1.13
- Python = 3.5

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of debugging, I've managed to find a solution.
The problem was that the Vertica dialect is just a patch and it inherits most of its behavior from the PostgreSQL dialect.

So, when inserting a new record, apparently what happens behind the scenes is sending a `nextval()` query to retrieve the next ID from the built-in sequence that **both Vertica and Postgres** create for auto-incrementing (or serial) fields.
So the generated ID is actually generated server-side.
**But**, while PostgreSQL allows inserting a value manually to a serial field, Vertica **doesn't**.

**Workaround:**
What I needed to do is make the ID field `INT`, without `auto_increment`, and then create a sequence manually, which has a name just like the automatically generated sequence (that is now deleted).
Something like:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE sometable_id_seq START 1;
```

**UPDATE:**
As [lv10](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175892/lv10) commented, an easier workaround could also be just using a raw SQL query an omit the ID argument.

Comment: I had the same problem and we worked around it by issuing single INSERT commands in raw sql, excluding the PK and allowing Vertica to assign it by itself. Multiple INSERTs  doesn't have this issue because vertica-python(uber maintained library) uses COPY. S

Comment: @lv10 yes of course that might be an even easier solution since it doesn't require updating your schema, I'll update my answer. Frankly I even kind of regret using Vertica with SQLAlchemy in the first place, We're now migrating to just using raw SQL. I had no idea that the compatibility is THAT bad...

Comment: This is my first time using vertica, it was already implemented when I joined the company where I work for. I am trying to get us to move to another DB, we already have problems querying views vertica_python doesn't supports it.